# What do I actually get for playing the Steam Monster Clicker game?

Tags: steam-monster-game

The description is a little vague, and I know that I [get cards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223314/how-do-i-get-card-drops-in-the-steam-summer-sale-game) for 'playing' it even if I don't actually keep clicking monsters, but other than the cards is there any reward for playing the Steam Monster Clicker game?

Comment: Are questions about games which don't work 99% of the time still on-topic?

Comment: @Studoku Well, we've still got [goat-simulator](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goat-simulator) questions, don't we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indeed get some cards by doing it.

You also get a 100xp-worth badge, for your steam profil, once you've reached the level 120. Note that you level up even when you do not play the game.

> EDIT: After being level 220, the badge you got at level 120 is
>   improved. This badge gives 125xp instead of 100.

It also helps the community to complete the objectives which put some games on sale. For example, the first objective unlocked a -50% on the game Crysis 2.

Comment: I haven't received a notification that I got this badge, but I've definitely gotten past level 220 - do I have to be in the game when I hit the right level for this to happen?

Comment: No, it just shows up in your profile based on your highest level achieved.  I'm not sure how the XP scales, but the badge for 1,000,000+ gives 200xp.

Comment: Yes, 200xp seems to be the maximum. I don't really know at what level it's  worth this amount but it doesn't have to be that high. My guess from what  I see is +25xp each 100 levels. Lv.100+ = 100xp, 200+ = 125xp... So the 200xp would be at level 500+.