# I've unlocked 10 cards from the Monster Game - where are they?

Tags: steam-trading-cards, steam-monster-game

The cards that it says I've unlocked aren't in my inventory. Do you just get them after the whole event? I have two from just buying games actually in my inventory, but the cards I've 'unlocked' aren't around. I'm Steam Level 7, so I know they should be dropping...

Comment: Where do see that it says that 10 cards are unlocked? Have you been playing the Monster Summer Game?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's on the community page with all the milestones, next to the Most Damage stat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be Steam Level 8 before you're awarded any of the cards you've unlocked. According to the [Monster Summer Game FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/minigame/#FAQ):

> ### How do I get Summer Sale trading cards?
>
> #### Play the Monster Summer Game
>
> If you’re Steam Level 8 and above, you’ll get a Summer Sale trading card at
>   random intervals while playing, up to three per 24-hour period. (If you reach
>   Steam Level 8 before the end of the sale, you’ll be granted the cards you
>   earned by playing the Monster Summer Game).

An earlier version of the FAQ incorrectly stated that level 5 was required.

Comment: Well that sucks. But thank you.