# Why am I not getting Steam Trading Card drops?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

I've been playing the steam Monster game and it tells me that I have received 4 cards from playing yet I have no cards in my Steam inventory? Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223899/ive-unlocked-10-cards-from-the-monster-game-where-are-they