# Why can't I get Steam Summer Sale trading cards by exploring my discovery queue?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

I got the problem that exploring my discovery queue doesn't give me any trading cards. After clicking through the list three times a day, it tells me to come back tomorrow to get more cards. But no cards appeared in my Steam inventory.

Do I have to change some settings to fix this? Does anyone else have the same issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that with "reviewing my shop list" you mean "exploring my discovery queue", you probably are not level 5 or higher. Check the [FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/my/stickers/):

> **How do I get Steam Summer Sale trading cards?**
>
> Steam Summer Sale trading cards are only available during the Steam Summer Sale. There are five ways to get the cards:
>
> [...]
>
> **Explore Your Discovery Queue**
>
> If you’re Steam Level 5 and above, you’ll get a Steam Summer Sale trading card once you view all the items in your daily Steam Discovery Queue. You can continue and go through your Discovery Queue two more times each day to get a maximum of three card drops each day. (If you reach Steam Level 5 before the end of the sale, you’ll be granted the cards you earned by exploring your Steam Discovery Queue during the sale).

There were similar constraints in earlier Steam sales, e.g. the [Summer Sale 2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223899/ive-unlocked-10-cards-from-the-monster-game-where-are-they).

(There doesn't seem to be a site with the whole rules that is not personalized.)

Comment: Yes, you assumed right, I edited my question. I'm currently level 4, now I know what the problem is, thanks!