# How to earn Monster Summer Sale cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

[image]

When I press the "Play game" button I get referred to the Monster game. While playing the game I just earn more card drops instead of the cards.

By playing the Monster game for a while I have earned 8 card drops, but where are the actual cards?

Comment: What Steam level are you?

Comment: I'm Level 31, but I don't know what this has to do with my question

Comment: See the duplicate question I linked to. Players under level 8 weren't receiving cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "card drops remaining" -number is misleading. It doesn't actually show how many drops are remaining, but how many drops you have **gotten so far**.

This is most likely because they only count how many cards you've got and are using the same template as other badges, but didn't bother to change the wording on it or reverting the number in any way.

The actual number of cards you can get is 3 times the number of sale days so far, minus the number you've already got. I'm not sure if you can get the cards retroactively. (If you didn't get all 3 on day one, can you get them on day two?)

Comment: You can only get cards retroactively if you achieve Steam level 8 during the sale. In that case you'll be awarded any card you had earned for playing the game but didn't receive because you weren't level 8 at the time. See this answer for how you actually earn cards: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/223925

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to get cards:

- You can earn up to two cards per day by playing that monster game
- You'll receive an additional card for every 10$ you spend at the store
- You'll be rewarded with an extra card for each badge you craft during the sale
- You can trade with others to get their surplus monster cards; there are several offers in the trading forum

As mentioned in the comments, [you have to be level 8 or above](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223899/ive-unlocked-10-cards-from-the-monster-game-where-are-they) to get the cards.